# Nomenclature Nomgroup font type change

Tags: fonts, nomenclature

My report should follow some guidelines, but I have no clue how to change them. I already read the nomencl description but could not find a clue on how to change the font of the nomgroups. I would like "latin"and "greek" to be in the same font as the rest. I am probably using this font \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} here is a picture of what it looks like now, and the code I used for this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter
\newif\if@nomlist 

\newcommand*\nomlist{%
  \@nomlisttrue
  \list{}{%
    \labelwidth\nom@tempdim
    \leftmargin\labelwidth
    \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
    \itemsep\nomitemsep
    \let\makelabel\nomlabel}}


\renewcommand*\thenomenclature{%
  \@ifundefined{chapter}%
    {\section*{\nomname}\if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nomname}\fi}%
    {\chapter*{\nomname}\if@intoc\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nomname}\fi}%
  \nompreamble
  \@nomlistfalse
}

\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \if@nomlist\endlist\end{multicols}\fi
  \ifx#1A\relax
    \def\nomgroupname{Latin}%
  \else
    \ifx#1B\relax
      \def\nomgroupname{Greek}%
    \else
      \def\nomgroupname{Other}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\noindent\textbf{\textsf{\nomgroupname}}]
  \nomlist
}

\renewcommand*\nompreamble{}
\renewcommand*\nompostamble{\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Please, add a minimal example with document code so at least a couple of nomenclature entries in both categories are produced.

Comment: Remove the `\textsf` in `\textbf{\textsf{\nomgroupname}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Great that did the trick! Thanks so much :)